# Append function of string builder not working in ssrs custom code

Tags: reporting-services

i have built a function in ssrs custom code but append function is not working and giving error "character is not valid"

```
Public Function fnErrRecommendation (ByVal ErrRecommendation As String 
) As String  
Dim Result As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

Dim ErrRecom As String() = ErrRecommendation.Split("|")
                for  i as Integer = 0 to ErrRecom.Length-1                      
                    IF (NOT String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrRecom(0))) THEN                        
                       Result=Result.Append(i + 1 + ".").Append(ErrRecom(i));
                        IF (i < ErrRecom.Length - 1) THEN

                           Result= Result.Append("<br><br>");
                        End If
                    End If

                Next

RETURN Result 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the embedded code language is VB you have to remove the semicolon from your code.

Also your code has the following errors:

You must convert i+1 to string before appending it to the string builder

```
Result=Result.Append(Cstr(i + 1) + ".").Append(ErrRecom(i))
```

Your function returns a string so you have to use ToString() method of string builder `RETURN Result.ToString()`